# Show a popup on page load and then show and hide it at regular time intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the disclaimer div to appear when a page first loads then show and hide it at regular time intervals after that. Showing it every three minutes would be a good time interval.

I currently have this code

```
<script>
function popup(){

setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById("disclaimer").style.display = "block";
},0);
}
function hidePopup(){
document.getElementById("disclaimer").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

I then need the popup to keep showing again after about 3 minutes time has elapsed.

Comment: Please add your code to the question itself- (read adding a [mcve])

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```js
//start showing popup
popup();

function popup() {

  document.getElementById("disclaimer").style.display = "block";

  console.log("wait 3 seconds then hide");

  setTimeout(hidePopup, 3000);

}

function hidePopup() {

  document.getElementById("disclaimer").style.display = "none";

  console.log("wait 3 minutes then show popup again");

  setTimeout(popup, 3 * 60 * 1000);

}
```

```html
<div id='disclaimer'>Disclaimer Div</div>
```

Comment: This is the best provided answer and should be accepted

Answer (score 1):

You can use setInterval to run code asynchronously at a specified interval of milliseconds. Then use setTimeout to delay the function so the pop shows for a period of time.

```
//function runs every 3 minutes
setInterval(function(){ 

   //function waits 1 second
   setTimeout(function(){
      popup();
   }, 1000);

   hidePopup();
}, 180000);
```

This function will run every 180000 milliseconds (3 minutes) and show the popup for 1000 milliseconds (1 second).

Answer (score 0):

Here how I would do it with one function only

snippet 1 (change time interval to how much seconds if needed)

```js
var dis_div = document.getElementById("disclaimer");
function init_disclaimer() {
  if (dis_div.style.display == "block"){
    dis_div.style.display = "none"
    }
  else {
    dis_div.style.display = "block"
  }
}
inter=setInterval(init_disclaimer,500)
```

```html
<div id="disclaimer">Disclaimer
</div>
```